# Cores em subreport

Tags: crystal-reports

Estou usando **Crystal Reports** para gerar um relatório. Este possui um sub Relatório, onde preciso acrescentar uma função de cor para uma seção.

Fiz da seguinte forma:

No sub Relatório.

Botão direito na seção > Section Expert > Aba Cor

```
if RecordNumber = 1 then crBlue else
if RecordNumber = 2 then crRed else
crNoColor
```

Bem, o objetivo é apresentar o primeiro item em azul, o segundo em vermelho e os seguintes sem cor.

Se essa função estivesse em alguma seção no Relatório Principal funcionaria perfeitamente (já testei), mas no sub relatório não funciona.

> Apenas o primeiro item recebe a cor (azul), mas o segundo fica sem
>   cor.
>
> O sub relatório foi inserido na seção do rodapé do relatório
>   principal.

Acredito que `RecordNumber` tem recebido `1` por conta da seção em que se encontra o sub relatório no Relatório Principal.

Detalhes do Crystal Reports:

**DLL:** CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine 
**Description:** Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 
**Runtime Version:** v2.0.50727 
**Version:** 13.0.2000.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era justamente esse:
Pelo **Sub Relatório** ter sido inserido na **seção de rodapé**, então `RecordNumber = 1`, pois o rodapé será "executado" apenas uma vez no **Relatório Principal**, e por algum motivo `RecordNumber` no **Sub Relatório** recebe o valor do **Relatório Principal**.

A alternativa foi usar uma função com uma variável compartilhada da seguinte forma:

No *Field Explorer* **Relatório Principal** criei a fórmula `CountSub` com o seguinte código:

```
Shared Numbervar x:= 0;
x;
```

Então arrastei a fórmula `CountSub` para a seção onde foi inserido o **Sub Relatório**, **e o suprimi**.

No *Field Explorer* **Sub Relatório** criei uma fórmula com o mesmo nome (`CountSub`) com o seguinte código:

```
Shared Numbervar x;
x:=x+1;
```

Então arrastei a fórmula `CountSub` para a seção onde queria ter o efeito das cores, **e o suprimi**.
Assim, a cada item ser "inserido", estarei acrescentando `+1` em `x`;

Então, 
Cliquei com o botão direito na seção > Section Expert > Aba Cor 
e inseri a seguinte fórmula:

```
if {@CountSub} = 1 then crBlue else
if {@CountSub} = 2 then crRed else
crNoColor
```

Assim, o controle pode ser feito pelo valor retornado pela função `CountSub`, que tem uma variável compartilhada `x` implementada nos códigos anteriores.